# fluid trapped inside cube without gravity

Tags: fluid-statics

A fluid in equilibrium is trapped inside a cube, outside the field of gravity. If a force F acts upon the centre of every seat of the cube via a piston of area A, what is the total pressure in the centre?

I think that the answer is $P=\dfrac{6F}{A}$ my textbook says it is $P=\dfrac{F}{A}$, why?

Comment: Well, this case is really the same as you have one piston and the other 5 walls are perfectly rigid.

Comment: we have six pistons, one in the centre of every seat of the cube...why it is the same,please explain if you can.

Comment: Why we cannot add the pressures?

Comment: The key is that nothing is moving. If the fluid pushes out with F/A, then the walls must push in with F/A or something will start moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each face of the cube the force is $F$ and the area is $A$ so the pressure exerted by this force is $\frac FA$.
To stop the face moving the fluid inside must also exert a pressure of $\frac FA$.
The pressure within all the fluid must be $\frac FA$ otherwise the fluid would start moving.
On the other faces there must also be forces of magnitude $F$ otherwise the faces would start moving.